# Отключение всплывающих окон через Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, всплывающее-окно

Я пытаюсь извлечь информацию со страницы в фейсбуке, используя Selenium. (пишу на Java). Проблема в том, что после захода на сайт, появляется всплывающее окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я не знаю, как его убрать. Пыталась при помощи команды

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

Или

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Но не реагирует. 
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Я нашла ответ на свой вопрос. При создании объекта WebDriver, нужно было настроить отключение уведомлений от браузера.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path/to/driver/exe");
WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Проблема решена.

Comment: Привет) У меня подобная проблема, но браузер Safari. Но у меня нет метода addArguments https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQF4L.png